# How to solve a php strtotime language issue not sincronyzed with server bash language

Tags: php, setlocale

I have a server which is running a German local language for Bash. When I try to change maillog time
in this server in Unix timestamp using ..

```
$time1="Mai-05-20 17:22:36";
$unix_time=strtotime($time1);
```

$unix_time returns empty, I think because bash is using German but PHP is running english (?).

How can I set the php script to run in the same language of Bash local language ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (emphasis mine):

> `strtotime` — Parse about any **English** textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

In case you don't need the full power of `strtotime()` (after all, you seem to be parsing logs from one single program) you can try [`IntlDateFormatter::parse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php). Here's a quick and dirty [demo](https://3v4l.org/mAIri):

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE', null, null);
$fmt->setPattern('M-dd-yy hh:mm:ss');
$log_time = "Mai-05-20 17:22:36";
$unix_time = $fmt->parse($log_time);
echo date('r', $unix_time);
```

> Tue, 05 May 2020 17:22:36 +0200

*Note that a Unix time is a fixed moment in time, thus unaffected by time zones. I get `+0200` when casting to local time because my [PHP default time zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is currently CEST.*

Comment: Ho can I solve if I receive a not english textual datetime because the server is set to German Locale language ?

Comment: `strtotime()` is a one-size-fits-all function that attempts to parse a very large number of freely formatted dates, from `2020-05-31` to `first sunday of novembre`. Do you really need to deal with that freedom?